# Norms on continuous function

Tags: integration, normed-spaces

Let $f(x)=x^2-x$, $x\in[-1,1]$. Find $\lVert f\rVert_2$.

Some other norms on $C[a,b]$:
$\lVert f\rVert_1=\int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x$.
$\lVert f\rVert_2=\left(\int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert^2~\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}$.

I know the answer to this problem is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, but am unable to solve it; the only way I get the answer is if I ignore the square. Can I get some help please?

Comment: Hint: $(x^2-x)^2=x^4-2x^3+x^2$.

Comment: Since you are only interested in $\|f\|_2$, what's the point of defining $\|f\|_1$?

Comment: How positive are you that the correct solution is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$?

Comment: 100% correct, that’s the answer given.

Comment: @Lorago already done this, it was first method does not provide the answer

Answer (score -1):

Following your definition of $\left\Vert f\right\Vert_2$ one can simply insert $f\left(x\right)=x^2-x$ into the formula and integrate the sum term by term:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\Vert f \right\Vert_2 &= \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1\left\vert x^2 - x\right\vert^2 dx}\\
&= \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1x^4-2x^3+x^2dx}\\
&= \sqrt{\left. \frac{1}{5}x^5 - \frac{1}{2}x^4 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 \right\rvert_{-1}^1}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\left(-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{3}} = \sqrt{\frac{16}{15}} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{15}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: answer as per text is sqrt(2/3)

Comment: Maybe you incorrectly transcribed the original definition in your question?

Comment: No, I did not. But I feel the answer provided is incorrect, I have tried various options but by no means it is  sqrt(2/3). for an abs function it is only positive in the region of -1<=x<0 for the function provided. The problem is they did not provide the solution in details.